# libjpeg package not found in torch?

Tags: torch, libjpeg

I am setting up torch in my system to run DCGAN code.
My system specification:

```
Ubuntu 18.04

CUDA-10.0
```

Torch distro that I am using : https://github.com/nagadomi/distro

I am getting this error libjpeg package not found while trying to run model training code

My hunch is that torch is not able to find libjpeg during the build. Is there a specific environment variable I have to set while building torch ?

BTW, I have libjpeg.so file present in /usr/lib64/

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Things that I have tried so far:

```
        Install libjpeg via sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev/turbo/devel etc. None of them work.
        Install latest version of libjpeg from http://www.ijg.org/files/
```

Error message and full stacktrace that I am getting:

```
...alleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/xlua/init.lua:360: module 'libjpeg' not found:
no field package.preload['libjpeg']
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file './libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file './libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)
...alleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/xlua/init.lua:360: module 'libjpeg' not found:
no field package.preload['libjpeg']
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file './libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file './libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)
...alleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/xlua/init.lua:360: module 'libjpeg' not found:
no field package.preload['libjpeg']
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file './libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file './libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)
...alleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/xlua/init.lua:360: module 'libjpeg' not found:
no field package.preload['libjpeg']
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file './libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file './libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)
...alleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/xlua/init.lua:360: module 'libjpeg' not found:
no field package.preload['libjpeg']
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file './libjpeg.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libjpeg/init.lua'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file './libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libjpeg.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
warning: <libjpeg> could not be loaded (is it installed?)
/home/wriders/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/distro/install/bin/luajit: ...Project/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:183: [thread 2 callback] 
...lleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:738: 
<image.loadJPG> libjpeg package not found, please install libjpeg
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
...lleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:738: in function 'error'
...lleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:232: in function 'loader'
...lleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:388: in function 'load'
...ts/AI/ArtGalleryProject/art-DCGAN/data/donkey_folder.lua:34: in function 'loadImage'
...ts/AI/ArtGalleryProject/art-DCGAN/data/donkey_folder.lua:54: in function 'getByClass'
...ocuments/AI/ArtGalleryProject/art-DCGAN/data/dataset.lua:341: in function <...ocuments/AI/ArtGalleryProject/art-DCGAN/data/dataset.lua:335>
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
...Project/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:234: in function 'callback'
...ryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:65: in function <...ryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:41>
[C]: in function 'pcall'
...ryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:40: in function 'dojob'
[string "  local Queue = require 'threads.queue'..."]:15: in main chunk
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
...Project/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:183: in function 'dojob'
...s/Documents/AI/ArtGalleryProject/art-DCGAN/data/data.lua:85: in function 'getBatch'
main.lua:180: in function 'opfunc'
...lleryProject/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/adam.lua:37: in function 'adam'
main.lua:236: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
...ect/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x55c83b254570
```